# Enviar foto selecionada na galeria para o banco junto com formulario, usando web service php

Tags: android

Boa pessoal, estou meio que apavorado, fiquei horas tentando codigos e não deu certo, enviar uma foto selecionada da galeria junto com alguns dados de um formulario em android, se alguem puder me dar uma luz ai agradeço

Comment: Adicione o que já tentou fazer de código, editando a pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Fala Juliano,

Para fazer esse serviço, você deve primeiro transformar a imagem escolhida em ByteArray e salvá-la no device do usuário.

Depois de feito essas duas etapas, ai sim você pode fazer o upload dela através de um web service.

Nesse [link](http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106), você pode ver um exemplo e até baixar um projeto teste pra ver como foi feito.

Ou você pode conferir esse código abaixo, que é o código apresentado no link de exemplo:

```
public class HttpFileUpload implements Runnable{
    URL connectURL;
    String responseString;
    String Title;
    String Description;
    byte[ ] dataToServer;
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;

    HttpFileUpload(String urlString, String vTitle, String vDesc){
            try{
                    connectURL = new URL(urlString);
                    Title= vTitle;
                    Description = vDesc;
            }catch(Exception ex){
                Log.i("HttpFileUpload","URL Malformatted");
            }
    }

    void Send_Now(FileInputStream fStream){
            fileInputStream = fStream;
            Sending();
    }

    void Sending(){
            String iFileName = "ovicam_temp_vid.mp4";
            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary = "*****";
            String Tag="fSnd";
            try
            {
                    Log.e(Tag,"Starting Http File Sending to URL");

                    // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)connectURL.openConnection();

                    // Allow Inputs
                    conn.setDoInput(true);

                    // Allow Outputs
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);

                    // Don't use a cached copy.
                    conn.setUseCaches(false);

                    // Use a post method.
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

                    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"title\""+ lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(Title);
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"description\""+ lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(Description);
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + iFileName +"\"" + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                    Log.e(Tag,"Headers are written");

                    // create a buffer of maximum size
                    int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                    int maxBufferSize = 1024;
                    int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    byte[ ] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                    // read file and write it into form...
                    int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                    while (bytesRead > 0)
                    {
                            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
                            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0,bufferSize);
                    }
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                    // close streams
                    fileInputStream.close();

                    dos.flush();

                    Log.e(Tag,"File Sent, Response: "+String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));

                    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

                    // retrieve the response from server
                    int ch;

                    StringBuffer b =new StringBuffer();
                    while( ( ch = is.read() ) != -1 ){ b.append( (char)ch ); }
                    String s=b.toString();
                    Log.i("Response",s);
                    dos.close();
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException ex)
            {
                    Log.e(Tag, "URL error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            }

            catch (IOException ioe)
            {
                    Log.e(Tag, "IO error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
  }

public void UploadFile(){
  try {
  // Set your file path here
  FileInputStream fstrm = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/DCIM/file.mp4");

 // Set your server page url (and the file title/description)
 HttpFileUpload hfu = new HttpFileUpload("http://www.myurl.com/fileup.aspx", "my file title","my file description");

 hfu.Send_Now(fstrm);

  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // Error: File not found
 }
 }
```

Abraços.